# Detect overflow when converting integral to floating types

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

The C standard, which C++ relies on for these matters as well, as far as I know, has the following section:

> When a value of integer type is converted to a real floating type, if the value being converted can be represented exactly in the new type, it is unchanged. If the value being converted is in the range of values that can be represented but cannot be represented exactly, the result is either the nearest higher or nearest lower representable value, chosen in an implementation-defined manner. If the value being converted is outside the range of values that can be represented, the behavior is undefined.

Is there any way I can check for the last case? It seems to me that this last undefined behaviour is unavoidable. If I have an integral value `i` and naively check something like

```
i <= FLT_MAX
```

I will (apart from other problems related to precision) already trigger it because the comparison first converts `i` to a `float` (in this case or to any other floating type in general), so if it is out of range, we get undefined behaviour.

Or is there some guarantee about the relative sizes of integral and floating types that would imply something like "float can always represent all values of int (not necessarily exactly of course)" or at least "long double can always hold everything" so that we could do comparisons in that type? I couldn't find anything like that, though.

This is mainly a theoretical exercise, so I'm not interested in answers along the lines of "on most architectures these conversions always work". Let's try to find a way to detect this kind of overflow without assuming anything beyond the C(++) standard! :)

Comment: 64-bit IEEE floating-point can represent any <=32-bit integer without loss of precision, and 32-bit IEEE floating-point can represent any <=16-bit integer. I'm not sure there is any other guarantee. Generally-speaking, a floating-point type with a significand of N bits or more can exactly represent any integer type of N bits or fewer.

Comment: Why not convert FLT_MAX to an integer first, instead of converting an unknown integer to FLT_MAX?

Comment: The question is funny. I do not think it can be solved in generic manner. For starters, Standard doesn't even mandate IEEE 754 for floats. I think, you will end up with implementation-specific logic, which knows how floats are represented and what their values are.

Comment: @chux the overflow when converting from float to integer is undefined behavior http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/10/09/Overflow-float-integer

Comment: @cdhowie not forgetting that the floating point significand has one more bit than is stored, since the normalised significand's m.s. bit is always `1` and so is implied (except for a value `0`).

Comment: @PascalCuoq Fair enough, my cite was integer to integer -removed.

Comment: implementation defined is implementation defined, that is kind of the definition.  you have to look at an implementation defined solution IF ANY to your question.  So specific version and build specific build options, specific target.  change any factor and you have to ask the question again.  So this is massively too broad for an SO question.

Comment: FLT_MAX is generally irrelevant although the size of an int, char, short are implementation defined so you could have a 128 bit int and a 32 bit float with a 20 something bit mantissa (the size of the mantissa plus any hidden or sticky bits is relevant and that is implementation defined, so see above).  actually a 128 bit int would need what a few bit float for FLT_MAX to be relevant?  FLT_MAX is irrelevant here.

Comment: and your title talks about overflow, you cant overflow a float (in general, one could create a compiler where this is true as mentioned) from an integer conversion.  you can lose precision but that that is not an overflow.  from float to int sure. but your question is about int to float.

Comment: even if you re-write the question to make it clear and consistent it is still too broad...implementation defined...meaning ask about the specific implementation.

Comment: @old_timer `uintmax_t` as a 128-bit type having a value of just exceeding `FLT_MAX` (overflow) is a real possibility and is a reasonable concern for OP writing code that uses such wide integers and narrow FP.

Comment: The C++ standard defines the behaviour of type conversions, it doesn't defer to C for that. It actually defers to C very little (primarily, behaviour of C standard library functions, and representations of primitive types)

Comment: if you have an unsigned int that can exceed the maximum floating point value in your compiler implementation, then why bother having floating point at all?

Comment: @chux what does the standard say uintmax_t is?  gcc does not appear to be assigning it a specific value...

Comment: yeah uintmax_t is a type not the number of bits in your implementation defined integer which you would need to compare to the number of bits in your implementation defined floating point mantissa plus other knowledge to answer this question.

Comment: this isnt even as easy as saying you cant fit a 32 bit integer into a single precision ieee 754 float.  Because you can, and it doesnt have to be less than 2^24 it can be 0xFFF00000 and can be exactly represented for example.  so you have to isolate the significant digits in your integer, count the number of bits, compare that to the number of significant digits stored by the floating point format then determine if the integer has more digits than the float can handle, and then you get your a little bigger or little smaller.

Comment: now if trying to shove a 64 bit integer into a half precision floating point number, you can not only easily exceed the number of bits for an exact representation but you can exceed the maximum value that float can represent overall.

Comment: I just don't get all the negativity (downvotes, close vote) on these absolutely legitimate questions that are useful in real world programming. Many uninteresting question whose answer won't help anyone except the confused person who posted get more upvotes. SO is broken!

Comment: @curiousguy you didnt read the whole statement you cant overflow a float from an integer conversion.  now granted I did demonstrate that with a half precision, but single on up using typical integers (32 bit, 64 bit) you wont overflow.  You can/will lose precision but that is something different, which is the key here that folks are confused about.  The quoted text is easy to understand as well as the situations that cause it...but implementation defined as one would expect, otherwise they would have to write hundreds of more pages...

Answer (score 4):

> Detect overflow when converting integral to floating types

`FLT_MAX`, `DBL_MAX` are at least 1E+37 per the C spec, so all integers with |values| of 122 bits or less will convert to a `float` without overflow on all compliant platforms.  Same with `double`

---

To solve this in the general case for integers of 128/256/etc. bits, both `FLT_MAX` and `some_big_integer_MAX` need to be reduced.

Perhaps by taking the log of both.  (`bit_count()` is a TBD user code)

```
if(bit_count(unsigned_big_integer_MAX) > logbf(FLT_MAX)) problem();
```

Or if the integer lacks padding

```
if(sizeof(unsigned_big_integer_MAX)*CHAR_BIT > logbf(FLT_MAX)) problem();
```

---

Note: working with a FP function like `logbf()` may produce an edge condition with the exact integer math with an incorrect compare.

---

**Macro magic** can use obtuse tests like the following that takes advantage the `BIGINT_MAX` is certainly a power-of-2 minus 1 and `FLT_MAX` division by a power of 2 is certainly exact (unless `FLT_RADIX == 10`).

This pre-processor code will **complain** if conversion from a big integer type to `float` will be inexact **for *some* big integer**.

```
#define POW2_61 0x2000000000000000u  
#if BIGINT_MAX/POW2_61 > POW2_61
  // BIGINT is at least a 122 bit integer 
  #define BIGINT_MAX_PLUS1_div_POW2_61  ((BIGINT_MAX/2 + 1)/(POW2_61/2))
  #if BIGINT_MAX_PLUS1_div_POW2_61 > POW2_61
    #warning TBD code for an integer wider than 183 bits
  #else
    _Static_assert(BIGINT_MAX_PLUS1_div_POW2_61 <= FLT_MAX/POW2_61, 
        "bigint too big for float");
  #endif
#endif
```

---

[Edit 2]

> Is there any way I can check for the last case?

This code will **complain** if conversion from a big integer type to `float` will be inexact **for a select big integer**.

Of course the test needs to occur *before* the conversion is attempted.

Given various rounding modes or a rare `FLT_RADIX == 10`, the best that can readily be had is a test that aims a bit low.  When it is true, the conversion will work.  Yet a *vary small* range of of big integers that report false on the below test do convert OK.

Below is a more refined idea that I need to mull over for a bit, yet I hope it provides some coding idea for the *test* OP is looking for.

```
#define POW2_60 0x1000000000000000u
#define POW2_62 0x4000000000000000u
#define MAX_FLT_MIN 1e37
#define MAX_FLT_MIN_LOG2 (122 /* 122.911.. */)

bool intmax_to_float_OK(intmax_t x) {
#if INTMAX_MAX/POW2_60 < POW2_62
  (void) x;
  return true; // All big integer values work
#elif INTMAX_MAX/POW2_60/POW2_60 < POW2_62
  return x/POW2_60 < (FLT_MAX/POW2_60) 
#elif INTMAX_MAX/POW2_60/POW2_60/POW2_60 < POW2_62
  return x/POW2_60/POW2_60 < (FLT_MAX/POW2_60/POW2_60) 
#else
  #error TBD code
#endif
}
```

Comment: @Julian Kniephoff Need anymore help on your post?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a C++ template function that returns the largest positive integer that fits into both of the given types.

```
template<typename float_type, typename int_type>
int_type max_convertible()
{
    static const int int_bits = sizeof(int_type) * CHAR_BIT - std::is_signed<int_type>() ? 1 : 0;
    if ((int)ceil(std::log2(std::numeric_limits<float_type>::max())) > int_bits)
        return std::numeric_limits<int_type>::max();
    return (int_type) std::numeric_limits<float_type>::max();
}
```

If the number you're converting is larger than the return from this function, it can't be converted. Unfortunately I'm having trouble finding a combination of types to test it with, it's very hard to find an integer type that won't fit into the smallest floating point type.

Comment: *"largest representable integer"* <-- I believe what you mean is it returns the largest representable integer that fits into both of the given types for which all smaller integers are also representable and fit into the given types.

Comment: @cdhowie I've changed the wording of that statement. Do I really need to explicitly state that smaller integers would also fit? It seems that should follow automatically.

Comment: I don't think it does follow. I'm sure there are larger integers that can be exactly represented, but are not *consecutive* integers.

Comment: @cdhowie OK, I see what you're saying now. The question specifies 3 different ranges: the range where *all* consecutive values can be represented, the range where some rounding can be expected, and the range that causes undefined behavior. An answer was only requested for the third case, and that's what this is.

Comment: Fair point, for some reason I thought the question was asking about the second case. Oops.